# What is the cheapest way to send fast website update alerts to users as push notifications?

Tags: amazon-web-services, twitter, rss, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to help an animal shelter deliver faster updates when a new pet is added to their website.  This is likely to happen between 0-20 times a day.

The website is a simple data dump, animals are in tables with row delineation (easy to parse) and have unique IDs.  When a new pet is added, ideally this would trigger a mobile notification to subscribed users (could also be an email message).  The faster updates are sent, the better, but checking every 30 mins or so would be fine.  Because this is for a charity, I want to spend as little as possible on resources (because I also want to be able to scale this up for other shelters that might want to use this).

For instance mobile notifications, Twitter seems to be a good candidate.  It looks like my needs wont run into fees/restrictions.

The part that I'm stuck on is how best to ping the site for updates and publish those updates to twitter.  The two options I've come up with are:

1. Build my own system.  Use a web crawler like Scrapy to periodically crawl the site and check for new petIDs.  Using AWS, I *think* I could get by with a nano instance (~$57 a year).  Using dynamoDB to cache existing petIDs seems like a small additional cost.  Use twitter API to post updates
2. Use an RSS feed generator like Feedity.  These seem to be pretty expensive: Feedity is $180/year for hourly updates and $390 for 15 minute updates.  Has API integrated with Twitter.

I'd like to know if there are any better/simpler/cheaper/more obvious options I may be overlooking.  Thanks!

Comment: can't create something inside their system? they should give you database access for what you can create a very easy trigger.

Comment: they don't have the time or resources or knowledge to do anything like that.  the database is controlled by a 3rd party